# Pass command line arguments to bash script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am new to bash script programming.

I want to implement a bash script 'deploymLog', which accepts as input one string argument(name).

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# ./deploymLog.sh name
```

here I want to pass the string argument(name) through command line

As an initial step, I need to append the current timestamp along with this input string to a log file say `Logone.txt` in current directory in the below format:

```
[name]=[System time timestamp1]
```

How it is possible?

Answer (score 139):

```
$> cat ./deploymLog.sh 
#!/bin/bash

name=$1
log_file="Logone.txt"

if [[ -n "$name" ]]; then
    echo "$1=$( date +%s )" >> ${log_file}
else
    echo "argument error"
fi
```

The first argument from a command line can be found with the positional parameter `$1`. `[[ -n "$name" ]]` tests to see if `$name` is not empty.
`date +%s` returns the current timestamp in Unix time. The `>>` operator is used to write to a file by appending to the existing data in the file.

```
$> ./deploymLog.sh tt

$> cat Logone.txt 
tt=1329810941

$> ./deploymLog.sh rr

$> cat Logone.txt 
tt=1329810941
rr=1329810953
```

For more readable timestamp you could play with `date` arguments.

Comment: total beginner here... it would be helpful to know what the `[[ -n "$name" ]]` part is doing.

Comment: The "[[ -n "$name" ]]" is another form of the "test" command.  
See:  http://ss64.com/bash/test.html

Answer (score 78):

Shell command line arguments are accessible via `$1` (the first), `$n` (the nth), or `$*` (all arguments), so your script should start:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo $0: usage: myscript name
    exit 1
fi

name=$1
```

Now the name argument is accessible from the script as `$name`.

To get the timestamp use the `date(1)` command and give it a format specifier so it produces the format you want:

```
now=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
```

Now `$now` contains the current date and time.

So you can create your log file thus:

```
logfile=/path/to/log/file/mylogfile.$now
echo "[$name]=[$now]" >> $logfile
```

You are better off using a shell function to log your messages as it will be easier to use:

```
function logit
{
    now=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
    echo "$now: $*" >> $logfile
}
```

Note that shell functions access their own arguments in the same way as the script (via `$1` etc.)

So the initial script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function logit
{
    now=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
    echo "$now: $*" >> $logfile
}

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo $0: usage: myscript name
    exit 1
fi

name=$1
now=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
logfile=/path/to/log/file/mylogfile.$now

logit name = $name
```

(note the log file isn't in the exact format you specified; it's in a better one with the timestamp at the start of each line).

Answer (score 9):

```
#!/bin/bash

name=$1

echo "$(date '+%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S') => " $name >> x.log
```

run "bash deploymLog.sh whatever", and you got x.log with

```
20120220-23:53:50 =>  whatever
```

Comment: I suppose the downvoter missed the reason of `name=$1`. The variable $name is never used, as you output only the string 'name' literally.

Comment: @DynoHongjunFu Still, the variable has same name and value, which is not a good way to make the example readable.

Comment: It is best to quote the var when assigning to name like this: `name="$1"`