# Bash: centos script to check disk usage in percentage only

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting

i have to do this script

```
./myscript.sh /a/dir1/vol/vol0
4%
```

i need to create a script then run it while typing the directory of mounted volume in the same line. then it should show only the percent of usage

Comment: as you can see, there is the script and then I have to type a directory of mounted volume. then the output will be just percent

what i did was 

df -h | grep vol0 | awk '{print $5}'
16%


but the problem is I can't turn it to script then provide the directory of mounted volume.

sorry i am really a beginner.

Comment: No worries. So, your problem is that you don't know how to pass a parameter from the command line to the script?

Comment: Thank you for understanding,

Yes, and actually I am really confused if it is really possible to execute the script like

Line 1: ./myscript.sh /a/dir1/vol/vol0
Lilne 2: 4%

line 1 will run myscript.sh and will use /a/dir1/vol/vol0 as input ( input can be changed depending on target volume)
line 2 will just show the current use%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to pass an argument (the mounted volume) to your script. Here is a very simple example (`dfScript.sh`) of how I would do that:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the volume from command line
volume="$1"

df -h "$volume" | egrep -o '[0-9]+%'

exit 0
```

Calling this would look something like:

```
./dfScript.sh /home/
12%
```

`$1` is the first argument passed to the script, in this case I used my `/home` directory as an example, but you can of course provide the path to any volume.

Also, you don't really need to assign `$1` to a variable to use it, I just did so above for clarity.

You can read more on passing arguments to bash **[here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32290/pass-command-line-arguments-to-bash-script#32293)**.

Comment: woah! exactly how it should be. I will remember this and play with it to familiarize it. Really thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem. Read the link I provided, it will tell you a lot about passing arguments to Bash and how it works (and doesn't work!).

Comment: I will, thank you for the reference as well. It will really be helpful.