# Taking filename as input when running script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

I have created a shell script which reads from csv File A (INPUT.csv) and then creates interim file from the data, do some operations and create another csv File B.
Later at the end it merges the two files INPUT.csv and B together to generate FinalOutput.csv.

Limitation of the script is if the file name is different then I have to either rename the file or make the change in the script else it will not read.
How can I make this dynamic so that whatever the name of the file is -- it should process and create the FinalOutput.csv

Sample script -

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F, '{print $2}' INPUT.csv > FileB.csv
{
Operations on File B
}
paste -d "," INPUT.csv FileB.csv > FinalOutput.csv

exit 0
```

Comment: It would help to see the actual script. Edit your question and include it. Hint: pass the file names as parameters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass command line arguments to bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32290/pass-command-line-arguments-to-bash-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the filenames of the input files as parameters when running the script.

You would then run the script with:

```
./script.sh INPUT.csv FileB.csv
```

Inside the script, refer to the parameters with variables `"$1"` and `"$2"`, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F, '{print $2}' "$1" > "$2"
{
# Operations on File B
}
paste -d "," "$1" "$2" > FinalOutput.csv

exit 0
```

Comment: You were a bit faster than me. You're missing quotes around parameters. Also, I believe OP wants *both* FileB and INPUT to be assignable.

Comment: Are quotes around the parameters required? I would believe it works just fine without. At least I have a lot of scripts with unquoted parameters that work without problem.

Comment: See https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html

Comment: Right - maybe in this particular case it would not make a difference, but generally a better idea - agreed!

Comment: Thanks.. This solved the problem.

Comment: It's often helpful to assign the positional parameters to variables with more descriptive names.