# Creating a directory from many variables

Tags: variable, mkdir

I want to create a script that creates a new folder with the name of the first argument in the directory specified as the second argument.

```
#!/bin/bash -e


## Passing Arguments (fastq data and directory where generate the output) into this script

 $fastq_file $new_directory

## Create the new directory

mkdir $new_directory/$fastq_file

# I have also tried mkdir "$new_directory"/"$fastq_file"
```

After saving and closing

I have tried to run the script with this

```
my_script 12345.fastq ./
```

The desired output should be a new folder in the current directory called 12345

If the user instead of `my_script 12345.fastq ./` would have been `my_script 12345.fastq /home/folder1/folder2`

I would like to get a new folder called 12345 in the directory /home/folder1/folder2

However, after many attends I always get the error: `` mkdir: cannot create directory `/': File exists ``

Comment: You seem to be asking how to [Pass command line arguments to bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32290/pass-command-line-arguments-to-bash-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood what you wanted correctly...

```
#!/bin/bash -e

new_directory=$1    
fastq_file=$2


mkdir -p $new_directory/$fastq_file
```

The script accept two arguments. First is the first directory name, second is the second directory name.

```
./script 12345 folder2
```

Comment: [Quote right](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).